# How can I ungeneralize generic type in type script

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```
interface returnSameInterface {
    returnSame<T>(input: T): T;
}

class TestString implements returnSameInterface {
    returnSame<string>(input: string) {
        return input;
    }
}

class TestNumber implements returnSameInterface {
    returnSame<number>(input: number) {
        return input;
    }
}
```

What I would want to achieve, is to define a class interface, that needs to implement a method, which will return something that has the exact same type, as it's input parameter. I want this interface to be generic, but when I am implementing this interface, in some cases I want to tell the implementing class, that it will only work with a specific type (as seen in my above example).

[Here's a fiddle also](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQyhArjMBlBAWygElJZEVUBvYVe9THfIqAHgBUA%20ACnAAcsEAFyoOASlEcA3MAC%20wYEgA2CAM5qxUNRDwQY4AOaoQhfsqjFImjNlwFiZaPGRpaDRnZbE2Og2ENeASFRPyNxGjoPBltmEzBBCFkPBQUlVQ0tHQA5LEIAI1gTMwsrCBsme1YnCldIj1iqnzA8wpgghJDUFoLYCPdo%20kaweMTkhlSgA)

Comment: Is it possible to move the generic type to the interface, and implement returnSameInterface<string> instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented looks like this. It could help you.

```
interface returnSameInterface<T> {
    returnSame(input: T): T;
}

class TestString implements returnSameInterface<string> {
    returnSame(input: string) {
        return input;
    }
}

var obj=new TestString();
console.log(obj.returnSame("test string"));
```

[Code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAihMBXKIDKcC2EAkuNPEgDwAqAfMgN4BQyLq6WuBEAFKAA4YwALmRUAlCKoBuRgF9GjBABs4AZ1WiIqsDjBRQAc2TB8fJRELgNaTNjyESkWIggVt%20kAbpNWbW50JeEAFhZHdDMQZmX1YbDmNgwRlfeXlFFXVNbQA5DHwAI2hjU3NLMGt2Oy5HMhcKEDzCqG9oljiqwP5BEQaC6EifGLbKkASQ5NZUhQA3OChkAHt8gCsAXhAIAHcsnT1DbjEZRln5peXcvqh1rZ2LpoOZBAWQVQXzADolBYNuM-f2gI8ABEkG0YT2niBYkOimerw%20Xx%20Zzu0H%20I3sPAAjAAGbGY6FSIA)